# MS Access Query for time In/Out attendance

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I'm doing a project which involves time and attendance management. When I download data from the biometric reader, I got the records in the following format,

```
USERID  CHECKTIME
5001    12/09/2011  09:05:34
5002    12/09/2011  09:33:13
5001    12/09/2011  13:05:53
5002    12/09/2011  13:22:24
5001    12/09/2011  14:05:22
5002    12/09/2011  14:33:53
5001    12/09/2011  18:05:09
5002    12/09/2011  17:44:34
```

This is the image [image]

I want to show the above records as follows,
(the Log_In, LB_Out, LB_In, Log_Out, WorkTime and LunchBreak are based on 'time')

This is the image [image]

Please help me out to make this query,

Comment: Do you mean that there is an assumption that you will find 4 timestamps, IN, OUT, IN and OUT, being the "OUT, IN" in the middle and indication of lunchbreak? If so, any solution you may device will be quite fragile... Imagine that a person does not have lunch break, or it takes it at the end of the day, or it forgets to punch the clock (sign IN/OUT with the biometric, or....).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, as you can see i have 4 logs for each person. 1st for IN, 2nd for BrackOut, 3rd for BrackIN, 4the for OUT or if someone how doesn't have a lunch break his/her 1st log would be as an IN and the last would be OUT.

Comment: please don't use external images unless strictly necessary: copy the output format to your question.

Comment: please put additional data from your comment into the **question**, otherwise others may miss it.

Comment: I'm not an SQL magician, but I doubt it can be done in pure SQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by userid and date and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.userid, datevalue(t.checktime) as [date],
  max(iif(t.counter = 0, t.checktime, null)) as Log_In,
  max(iif(t.counter = 1, t.checktime, null)) as LB_Out,
  max(iif(t.counter = 2, t.checktime, null)) as LB_In,
  max(iif(t.counter = 3, t.checktime, null)) as Log_Out,
  Format((Log_In - LB_Out) + (LB_In - Log_Out), "HH:mm:ss") as WorkTime,
  Format(LB_In - LB_Out, "HH:mm:ss") as LunchBreak
from (
  select t.*,
    (select count(*) from tablename where userid = t.userid and datevalue(checktime) = datevalue(t.checktime) and checktime < t.checktime) as counter
  from tablename as t
) as t
group by t.userid, datevalue(t.checktime)
```

Results:

```
userid  date        Log_In                  LB_Out                  LB_In                   Log_Out                 WorkTime  LunchBreak
5001    12/9/2011   12/9/2011 9:05:34 am    12/9/2011 1:05:53 pm    12/9/2011 2:05:22 pm    12/9/2011 6:05:09 pm    08:00:06  00:59:29
5002    12/9/2011   12/9/2011 9:33:13 am    12/9/2011 1:22:24 pm    12/9/2011 2:33:53 pm    12/9/2011 5:44:34 pm    06:59:52  01:11:29
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the statement. I have tried your SQL statement, but it only shows me a date-wise 1st log only.

Comment: Yes, i just change tablename to dbo_CHECKINOU

Comment: I tried this code with your sample data (and additional for other days too) and it returns the results that you expect. If your data is not as you describe in the question: 4 rows for each user per date then I can't tell.

Comment: thanks, it is now working. But if someone doesn't have lunch brack so that his/her 1st   wouldn't be IN and 2nd OUT?

Comment: Sorry! for not responding as fast as you. I'm a new user of StackOverflow.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment this code works if there are 4 rows for each user per day as you posted the requirement in the question. If you have a different requirement then you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thank You! Sir, for your support.